# Expression to find value for previous year SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx

I need some help with expressions.I need a report that shows calcul of a field for current year as well as previous year respecting this rule expression(Last-Last Previous)/Last Previous*100. Also the report runs on a Year Parameter. 
Below is an example for the result
for example i selected the years 2010 2011 2012

```
       year
 Data        2010    2011   2012  
 hp          14      25     30    
 Dell        17      18     20
```

and the result i want

```
     year
 Data        2010    2011   2012  2011/2012 
 hp          14      25     30       0.002     (Last -Last Previous)/(last Previous*100) =(30-25)/(25*100) 
 Dell        17      18     20       0.0040
```

How can i do this

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Val]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [DimCAT].[lbl].[lbl].ALLMEMBERS * [DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Data];
```

Comment: Pivot the query Year wise then you are able to apply you expression.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more

Comment: can you add the MDX query you are using?

Comment: this the MDX query
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Val] } ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY { ([DimCAT].[lbl].[lbl].ALLMEMBERS * [DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS FROM [Data]

Answer (score 0):

Via `mdx` you need to use a `WITH` clause.
The `calculated member` that is added is called `2011/12` but is actually the last member of the year hierarchy compared to the previous year - so maybe not exactly what you require:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [DimDate].[Year].[2011/12] AS 
        (
          Tail([DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS).Item(0).Item(0)
        - 
          Tail([DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS).Item(0).Item(0).PrevMember
        )
      / 
        Tail([DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS).Item(0).Item(0).PrevMember
    * 100 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [DimDate].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS
     ,[DimDate].[Year].[2011/12]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[DimCAT].[lbl].[lbl].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Data]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Val];
```

Using the `strToSet` function you could get a single member set using the parameter:

```
WITH 
  SET [s] AS 
    StrToSet('{[DimDate].[Year].[Year].[' + @Yr + ']}') 
  MEMBER [DimDate].[Year].[LastVsPrev] AS 

        ([s].Item(0).Item(0) - [s].Item(0).Item(0).PrevMember)
      / 
        [s].Item(0).Item(0).PrevMember
    * 100 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Union
    (
      {
        [s].Item(0).Item(0).PrevMember.PrevMember : [s].Item(0).Item(0)
      }
     ,{[DimDate].[Year].[LastVsPrev]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[DimCAT].[lbl].[lbl].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Data]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Val];
```

Comment: but i have  the report runs on a Year Parameter

Comment: ok - so you have `@Yr` which is equal to the year in the final column? i.e. `@Yr` = `2012` ?

Comment: ok so @yr might be 2012, 2013 or 2014 depending what the user selects?

Comment: exactly i didn't found a solution how can you do this because my problem is the last previous value in ssrs i have the function Last to get the last value but the last previous i don't have a function

Answer (score -1):

If you have the chance to change the source dataset i would bring the dataset with the year UNPIVOTed and with a Row_Number on Data with year descending order. That way you can filter the last two years you want.
(this was tested in SSRS 2008 there might be easier ways especially in later versions)

```
   select 
        Data,[year],measure,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by data order by [year] desc) i
    from (values 
    ('hp',2010,14), 
    ('hp',2011,25), 
    ('hp',2012,30),
    ('Dell',2010,17),
    ('Dell',2011,18),
    ('Dell',2012,20)) t (data,year,measure)

 Data        year    measure   i
 hp          2010    14        3
 hp          2011    25        2
 hp          2012    30        1
 Dell        2010    17        3
 Dell        2011    18        2
 Dell        2012    20        1
```

And do a Column Group on year and a row group on data.
Expression *SUM(Field!Measure.Value)* on the intersecting cell of the 2 groups.

Add Column after column group and add the Expression to the Header cell

```
=MAX(iif(Fields!i.Value = 2,Fields!year.Value.ToString(),""))+"/"+ MAX(iif(Fields!i.Value = 1,Fields!year.Value.ToString(),""))
```

and the next expression to the Cell

```
=iif(SUM(iif(Fields!i.Value = 2,Fields!measure.Value,0))=0,0,SUM(iif(Fields!i.Value = 1,Fields!measure.Value,0))-SUM(iif(Fields!i.Value = 2,Fields!measure.Value,0)) / (SUM(iif(Fields!i.Value = 2,Fields!measure.Value,0))*100))
```

I think the formula is OK, but it's returning different values than what you posted as expected.

Comment: thanks for answer but i work with mdx qeury i'am triying to write a script with vb.net to get me the last previous value